# Inserting collection into database

Tags: mysql

Is there any solution for inserting collection as seperate column in database table. For example:

Table: OrderDetails
OrderId
CustomerId
ProductId -> this should be an array or list (ProductIds)
...

Is there something like array or list in mysql or should I split order into seperated orders according to amount of different products?

Thanks ind advance.

Comment: Dont store comma separated data, instead create another table as `product_orders` with fields `orderid and productid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put a list of things into a column.  What you need is a separate table called Products.

This table would contain an OrderId column and a ProductId column.  If you have 3 products for a particular order then you would have 3 rows for that order in the products table.  You would put one element in the list on one line in the product table.

```
Table: Products
OrderId
ProductId
```

This is known as normalisation and is an important thing to understand in designing relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading up a little on "Normalisation". Ideally, you'd get to Boyce-Codd Normal Form. See [The Wikipedia on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

If you don't want to have joins, you probably don't want to use a relational database and may want to consider an object store or noSQL solution which would let you store a JSON document directly.